(Why) does spark structured streaming recompile the code for each mini-batch
I have a spark structured streaming job, reading from Kafka, parsing avro, exploding a column, computing some extra columns as simple combinations (sum/product/division) of existing columns, and write the result to delta table. No windows or state, and not using foreachbatch.
I am struggling to get the latency down, and in the logs I see statements like

24/05/20 19:09:53 INFO CodeGenerator: Generated method too long to be JIT compiled: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.generate_doConsume_1$ is 43612 bytes
24/05/20 19:09:53 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 249.483881 ms

And from the timestamps they seem to correspond to the micro-batches. After having enabled debug log, I see that it is in fact the same code which gets generated for every micro-batch.
This raised the following questions:

Is this as expected, or is it a sign of something being wrong?
If it is as expected, what is the rationale? The transformations I want done is the same for every batch, why regenerate and recompile code instead of just using the old code on the new data?
I found this cache, is it supposed to help?


Each microbatch is re-Catalyzed as it were. That is to say, each microbatch is a new query. The required query plan could change, but will more often than not remain static. It's a design aspect (for the future).
Caching can help as you allude to. Set spark.sql.codegen.cache.maxEntries accordingly to improve performance. Some suggest a larger batch interval.

Thanks for the reply! What do you mean by the "for the future", is this something that might change? And I have already set spark.sql.codegen.cache.maxEntries to 99999, but I still see "CodeGenerator: Code generated in" for every batch. I dont know much Scala, but from the cache it seems like that means a cache-miss. Would the normal thing be that it does not spit out the "Code generated" for each microbatch?

https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/generated-method-too-long-be-jit-compiled/read

Yeah I thought it might be related to the large method error, but I tried now again with a smaller pipeline withouth the "Generated method too long to be JIT compiled" error, and it also shows that the code gets compiled for every microbatch. So is it completely normal that we get the "Code generated in..." message for each batch?

Not all software works correctly as the article states. For the future therefore I stated

At this point in time it is completely normal as the docs state. As you observe yourself. As bartosz points out.
